# Python Coverage Says Line A is Covered, Need to Know From Where

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, code-coverage, agile

I have a **coverage report that may be lying or distorted**.  It says that I have coverage for a line in my Django model code.  I can't see where that line is being exercised.  I can see that the module is imported, that the class is imported, but not that it's being invoked/instantiated.

Thus, coverage report says I have Line A covered.  Presumably that means Line B, somewhere, is exercising it.  I'd like to know where Line B is.  ***Is there a way to find the set of Line-B's*** (one or more) that are calling Line A, in my tests?

It seems this could be an annotation in the coverage report somehow/somewhere.  It's definitely knowable, since coverage has to keep track of a thing being used.

I'm not seeing it.

If this isn't implemented, I'd like to suggest it.  I know, it may be too complex as a full stack trace for each line of execution.  But, maybe just the inspect of the immediate calling frame would be a good start, and helpful.

Comment: Just add an `import traceback; traceback.print_stack()` before the line in question and run tests with the `-s` arg.

Answer (score 4):

New in coverage.py 5.0 are [dynamic contexts](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-5.0.3/contexts.html#dynamic-contexts) which can tell you what test ran each line of code.  It won't tell you the immediate caller of the line, but it's a start.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a fun way to discover what covers that line:

Insert a bug in the line.

If you then run the tests, the ones truly covering the line will fail. The stacktraces should include Line B.

Comment: The previous answer of dynamic contexts seems to be the best one, I'm going to try that. Sure, I can add bugs for a line (pdb set trace, also) but I'm looking for where a large set of lines are covered from, not just one.  Thank you, though.

Comment: You can easily comment out large sets of lines (or modify them to compile/run but not do something correct). Tests which then fail are truly testing the lines (as opposed to just executing them for "coverage"). See also: mutation testing.